# Android Studio cannot run the Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to simulate my Flutter app with the Xcode iPhone Simulator and I get this error. Before upgrading Android Studio and Xcode it was working fine.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '/Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

Using:

- macOS 10.13.6 (17G65)
- Android Studio 3.2 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 18, 2018
- Xcode 10.0 (10A255)
- Xcode Simulator 10.0 (SimulatorApp-869.5 CoreSimulator-572.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed in `master` channel

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890

> ### Workarounds
>
> There are two workarounds:
>
> - **Option 1: Use the legacy build system .** As noted by @gi097, open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`, and change the build system to `Legacy Build
>     System`.
> - **Option 2: Use the new Xcode 10 build system.**
>
>   1. Open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`
>   2. Select the `Runner` project in the project navigator sidebar.
>   3. In the main view, select the `Runner` target, then select the `Build Phases` tab.
>   4. Expand the `Embed Frameworks` phase and select `Flutter.framework` from the embedded frameworks list.
>   5. Click `-` to remove `Flutter.framework` from the list (be sure to *keep* `App.framework`).