# Cannot build Flutter application for Xcode Simulator using Android Studio Flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I would like to ask how to compile my Flutter app for real devices or the simulator. Before these problems occurred, I could compile the Flutter app for iOS, but after the updates of Xcode + Flutter + AS, suddenly it can no longer run any Flutter apps.

Xcode itself can run the apps without any problems, but when I execute the command `flutter run` I get the following error:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         9.4s
Xcode build done.                                           36.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-12-17 11:10:56.911 xcodebuild[21278:254935] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfceca2180), xxx’s iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80),
    00008020-000928A82293802E> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2020-12-17 11:10:56.912 xcodebuild[21278:254935] [MT] iPhoneConnect: Failed
    _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by
    passcode.
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: 5
    Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fbfcb11ed40:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fb
    fcb11eac0:'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneO
    S.platform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
    User Info: {
        DVTDeviceDescription = "\Ud83d\Udcf1<DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfceca2180),
        xxx\U2019s iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80),
        00008020-000928A82293802E>";
    }
    --
    2020-12-17 11:10:56.912 xcodebuild[21278:254935] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbfceca2180), xxx iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80),
    00008020-000928A82293802E> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
        ** BUILD FAILED **
.........

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

This is the error I got from running (Flavor / newly created project). Currently, I can't run any flavor using Xcode, I can only run non-flavor projects from Xcode.
So far, I have tried:

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890
2. [Android Studio cannot run the Xcode Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533352/android-studio-cannot-run-with-ios-simmulator)
3. flutter clean && flutter run
4. Logging out of Xcode
5. Closing and reopening Xcode
6. Killing Xcode in the terminal.

If you have any ideas please let me know. I really am stuck with this kind of error using emulator or real device, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got fixed my issue after I tried to uninstall the second XCode, so this problems occurred because when previously I tried using my MAC I install the XCode beta version, then tried to publish my apps into playstore, because of XCode version I downloaded from AppsStore another XCode version, this somehow make clash for android studio to detect and occured this kind of error, hope this help when someone has this kind of issue